# Printing a php variable in a html tag which was already echoed inside a php tag

Tags: php, html

I am having trouble to print a variable in a html tag which was already echoed in a php tag?I want to print $A variable in h1 tag. my code:

```
  <?php 
   while($pr = mysql_fetch_assoc($qAccess))

    {  

        $id=$pr["user_id"];                             
        $A=$pr["name"];

    }

echo  "<html  

 <!-- Profile info -->

        <div id='profile_info'>

            <h1 id='name' class='transition-02'>$A</h1>

            <h4 class='line'>no heading</h4>

            <h6><span class='fa fa-map-marker'></span> San Francisco , CA</h6>

        </div>

        <!-- End Profile info -->

</html>" ;  
?>
```

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get any errors? What do you get and what do you expect ?

Comment: That should already work :) https://eval.in/445359

Comment: It's echoing no heading and San Francisco , CA. Is that what you're expecting?

Comment: It should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put the echo in the while loop.
If you don't do this, it will only display the last occurence of your array.

Try this:

```
<?php 

    echo "<html>";

    while($pr = mysql_fetch_assoc($qAccess)) {

        $id = $pr["user_id"];
        $A = $pr["name"];

        echo "<!-- Profile info -->

            <div id='profile_info'>

                <h1 id='name' class='transition-02'>$A</h1>

                <h4 class='line'>no heading</h4>

                <h6><span class='fa fa-map-marker'></span> San Francisco , CA</h6>

            </div>

        <!-- End Profile info -->";
    }

    echo "</html>" ;  

?>
```

Else it might be because the `<html>` is not properly closed in your code.

Comment: It's outputting the same thing whether it has a closed html tag or not.

Comment: Wow @jessica, you are like Lucky Luke. Minus 1 faster than your shadow.

Comment: And you're assuming the worst of people faster than your shadow. I only commented on your post.

Comment: Damn it Jessica, I deeply apologise. We have another Lucky Luke in SO then :-)

Comment: use this `echo "<h1 id='name' class='transition-02'>{$A}</h1>";`

Answer (score -2):

2 options
- Options 1:

```
<div id='profile_info'>

    <h1 id='name' class='transition-02'><?=$a?></h1>

    <h4 class='line'>no heading</h4>

    <h6><span class='fa fa-map-marker'></span> San Francisco , CA</h6>

</div>
```

- Options 2:

```
    <?php
    echo "<html>  
        <!-- Profile info -->

            <div id='profile_info'>

                <h1 id='name' class='transition-02'>".$A."</h1>

                <h4 class='line'>no heading</h4>

                <h6><span class='fa fa-map-marker'></span> San Francisco , CA</h6>

            </div>

        <!-- End Profile info -->

        </html>"
?>
```

Comment: What is the solution? Problem itself is vague , how can this be referenced as an answer?

Comment: @HuongNV option 1 and 2 both are returning nothing. if i use single quote in option 2 like this>> '.$A.'   then it is only returning '..'